# DOM tree elements with classes, are they global variables?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How About the class swim, why can't it be accessed globally?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<section id="sports">
        <p class="swim">Swim</p>
        <p id="bike">Bike</p>
        <p>Run</p>
</section>
```

Comment: how are you trying to access it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'accessed globally'?

Comment: I'm accessing like, swim.methodOrProperty. I just noticed that for ids I can do like bike.methodOrProperty.

Comment: Do you understand the answer I just gave you?

Comment: Yes I understand your answer just wondering why classes can't be accessed the ways like ids.

Answer (score 0):

The node with the CSS class `.swim` is actually global, as is any node in the document.

You would access it in CSS like `.swim { display: none; };`

In Javascript `document.querySelectorAll('.swim')[0].style.display = 'none';`

or jQuery $('.swim');

**Here is a demo http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/zqNaME**

Comment: Why use `querySelectorAll()[0]` instead of `querySelector`?

Answer (score 0):

> How about the class `swim`, why can't it be accessed globally?

No, unlike IDs, you cannot access an element "globally" (via the `window` object) using its class. The reason is that that is not the spec.

What would that mean anyway? Many elements have the same class, so what would `window.<class>` mean? Would it be an array? HTML can have dozens or hundreds or thousands of elements with the same class.

It would also be extremely slow to have to update all these global objects every time a class on an element changed. And there's so need for it, since you have `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelector[All]`.

By the way, accessing elements via their IDs from the `window` object is not considered best practice anyway.